# MPI: get ranks of all processors in a given communicator

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm given a communicator, how do I get all the ranks of the processors in that communicator?

All I can find is to how to get the number of processors in a given communicator, but there doesn't seem to be a function to get a collection of ranks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranks are always assigned linearly. If your communicator has size `p`, then the ranks of all the processors will be `0, 1, 2, ..., p-1`.

If your communicator is a sub-communicator of MPI_COMM_WORLD, then processors will be relabeled with ranks from `0` to the size of the sub-communicator.

If you are looking for the global ranks (as assigned in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`) of the processors of your sub-communicator. You'll have to use a `MPI_Gather` or `MPI_Allgather` with the processes rank in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`:

```c
// get global rank
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
// getting size of your communicator
int size;
MPI_Comm_size(your_comm, &size);
// all-gather global ranks
int * ranks = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
MPI_Allgather(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, ranks, 1, MPI_INT, your_comm);
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Patrick's answer:

To get rank of processes from comm_1 to comm_2 or visa versa you can first extract the underlying `MPI_Group` and then use [MPI_Group_translate_ranks](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Group_translate_ranks.html)

```
MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
MPI_Comm my_comm;

int n;
MPI_Comm_size(comm, &n);

int rank1[n] = {0,1,2,3,...}
int rank2[n];

// Some Code

MPI_Group world_group;
MPI_Group my_comm_group;

MPI_Comm_group(comm, &world_group);
MPI_Comm_group(my_comm, &my_comm_group);

MPI_Group_translate_ranks(world_group, n, rank1, my_comm_group, rank2);
```

You will get array rank1 corresponding ranks in array rank2.